# Using the docusign api c# access code for authentication of signer

Tags: docusignapi

Using the sample C# send document API call, how can I send a data element located in my system, such as zip code or last 4 of ssn, to be enable this as an access code to view the document? This way I know that the person signing has another level of authentication tat ties back to the signer.

Comment: Also check out the ID Check stuff if that's an option for you. It costs some money, but it's a great way to actually verify that customers are who they say without requiring them to log in to a separate system.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read through the [DocuSign API documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation) yet?  Just add the `accessCode` property to your signer JSON object and give it a value.  Basically, something like this:

```
"recipients": 
 {
    "signers": [
     {
        "email": "test_1@email.com",
        "name": "Name 1",
        "accessCode": "1234",

        ...
```

Description from API docs:

"*This Optional element specifies the access code a recipient has to enter to validate their identity. This can be a maximum of 50 characters.*"

Comment: I am using XML as shown below from the sample C#. See below. Can it be done using this method?

Comment: // add document(s)
    "<documents>" +
    "<document>" +
    "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
      "<name>" + documentName + "</name>" +
    "<name>" + args [2] + "</name>" +
    "</document>" +
    "</documents>" +
    // add recipient(s)
    "<recipients>" +
    "<signers>" +
    "<signer>" +
    "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
      "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +
    "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
    "<name>" + args [0] + "</name>" +
    "<email>" + args [1] + "</email>" +
    "<AccessCode>1234</AccessCode>" +  
    "<tabs>" +

Comment: This is a really cool answer. I had no idea about the accessCode property. I'm going to sock that away for next time.